# Data from db undefined at first, then changes to actual data

Tags: meteor

I am doing a find on a collection of nodes and am then storing the info in a variable.

I am then console.logging this data to see the contents of it. The thing is, my data stays an empty array for a split second and then a new console.log is done with an array of data. See my code below:

```
Template.temperature.helpers({
    node() {
        let node = Nodes.find({_id:Session.get('selectedNode')});
        console.log(node);
        return '';
    }
});
```

My console output:

```
1: []
2: [Object]
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Where is your subscription logic?

Comment: My subscription logic simply consists of Meteor.subscribe('nodes');
My publish consists of: 
`Meteor.publish('nodes', () => {
    const nodes = Nodes.find({}, {fields: {data: {$slice: 5}}});
    return nodes
});`

The subscription file is located in my client folder, the publication file in my server folder.

Comment: Does the subscription load when the temperature template loads? If so, this is the intended behavior. Helper functions are reactive, and therefore re-run as the data changes. The first time it runs, the subscription was not ready, therefore it printed `[]`. Once the subscriptions was ready, the helper ran again (as it should) and found the object.

Comment: I just added a callback with a console.log inside of my subscription. The console now shows:
`subscribed!
map.js:4 []
map.js:4 [Object]`

My file structure: http://imgur.com/LRgfUys

Comment: I need to know when the subscription is being called. Is it called in Template.temperature.onRendered()?

Comment: Nope, it's being called in my /client/subscriptions folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100070/discussion-between-jori-and-brendan-turner).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your router, subscribe within waitOn:

```
Router.route('/home', {
    waitOn: function() {
        return [
            Meteor.subscribe('nodes'),
        ];
    },
    action: function() {
        if (this.ready()) {
            this.render();
        }
    },
});
```

This will ensure that the route will wait until the subscription is completed before executing the route. It uses the meteor loading hook, so the wait will utilize whatever loading screen or animation you ahve setup.